# Why is my DOCTYPE showing up as red italic in Firefox page source?

Tags: firefox, xhtml, doctype

When viewing my page in Firefox page source, I am getting the first line in red italic:

[image]

What is causing this and is it an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mouse over the doctype you'll see that Firefox is rendering the page in "[Almost standard mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko%27s_Almost_Standards_Mode)".

> The DOCTYPEs that will trigger "almost standards" mode are those which
>   contain:
>
> - The public identifier "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
> - The public identifier "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN"
> - The public identifier "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN", with a system identifier
> - The public identifier "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN", with a system identifier
> - The IBM system DOCTYPE "http://www.ibm.com/data/dtd/v11/ibmxhtml1-transitional.dtd"
>
> A complete DOCTYPE contains a public identifier and a system
>   identifier. In discussions of DOCTYPEs, many people will refer to a
>   DOCTYPE as being "with URI" or "without URI." The URI is the system
>   identifier. For example, consider the following DOCTYPE:
>
> ```
>  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> The parts are as follows:
> ```
>
> - Public Identifier: "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
> - System Identifier: "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"
>
> Thus any HTML 4.01 Transitional or Frameset DOCTYPE with a URI (system
>   identifier) will trigger "almost standards" mode, as will any XHTML
>   1.0 Transitional or Frameset DOCTYPE, with or without the URI. Authors outside of IBM do not need to worry about the custom DOCTYPE that will
>   also trigger "almost standards" mode.